# Login with code when using LiveServerTestCase with Django

Tags: django, selenium, integration-testing

So I have a Selenium functional test suite. I've already tested login/signup functionality in a few tests by navigating the Selenium client to the signup page, entering in a username and password, and then telling Selenium to login with those same credentials. Now I want to test other parts of the "login required" areas of the site without having to tell Selenium to click and enter text into the test browser.

In other words, I would like to use something like this (which I use just fine in my view unit tests):

```
self.client = Client()  
self.user = User.objects.create_user('temporary', 'temporary@gmail.com', 'temporary')  
self.user.save()  
self.client.login(username='temporary', password='temporary')
```

in my Selenium tests so I don't have to repeat the lengthy manual login process in every one of my tests (since I've already tested the login system in earlier tests as I said before)

As of right now, I just copy and paste the 'login flow' Selenium instructions for each of my tests that require login. This causes my tests to take an addition 5-6 seconds each and it makes my function_tests.py file very bloated.

All my Googling has brought me to pages teaching me how to test login with Selenium.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't login user from selenium driver. It's just impossible without some hacks.

But you can login once per TestCase by moving it to setUp method.

You can also avoid copy-pasting by creating your class inherit from LiveServerTestCase.

**UPDATE**

This code worked for me:

```
self.client.login(username=superuser.username, password='superpassword') #Native django test client
cookie = self.client.cookies['sessionid']
self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/admin/')  #selenium will set cookie domain based on current page domain
self.browser.add_cookie({'name': 'sessionid', 'value': cookie.value, 'secure': False, 'path': '/'})
self.browser.refresh() #need to update page for logged in user
self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/admin/')
```

Comment: Just to clarify, by "You can also avoid copy-pasting by creating you class inhereted from LiveServerTestCase." you mean that you would create a MyBaseTest class that inherits from LiveServerTestCase and then inherit from MyBaseTest for your actual test classes, correct?

Comment: This answer works great for cleaning up code, but my tests still take about a minute longer to execute since logging in with facebook requires the extra step of going to facebook.com. Oh well.

Comment: You can try to log in user with:

    self.client.login(username='temporary', password='temporary')

Then get sessionid cookie:

    self.client.cookies[settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME]

And set it in selenium driver:

    self.browser.execute_script(''' var date = new Date( new Date().getTime() + 60*1000 );
document.cookie="sessionid=%s; path=/; expires="+date.toUTCString();''' % sessionid)

I didn't check it but think that it might work.

Comment: Please comment if you will success with this code, may be I should update my own tests )

Comment: I can get the javascript to execute but when I refresh I'm still not logged in. I think this is because the Selenium test uses webdriver.Firefox() as the client which is not the same as the client we logged in with.

Comment: Django uses sessionid cookie to define user.
If you set correct coockie in webdriver and reload current page then django will think that user is the same user that you logged in with native client.

Comment: Is there a way to log in without doing `self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + '/admin/')` first? It still takes some time.

Comment: No, selenium can set cookie only for current domain. And current domain is taken from current page.

Comment: This isn't working for me, `self.client.cookies` seems to be empty and I'm getting a `KeyError` on Django 1.8

Comment: Try to print self.client.cookies and check what is inside. Maybe you've changed session cookie name?

Comment: Likewise: `self.client.cookies` is empty for Django 1.10  ... printing its shows nothing.

Comment: with this method, using `request.user` shows that it's an [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object). Not exactly what we may want...

Comment: Had to find class `Client` first - if others have same problem: `from django.test import Client`

Answer (score 18):

In Django 1.8 it is possible to create a pre-authenticated session cookie and pass it to Selenium.

In order to do this, you'll have to:

1. Create a new session in your backend;
2. Generate a cookie with that newly created session data;
3. Pass that cookie to your Selenium webdriver.

The session and cookie creation logic goes like this:

```
# create_session_cookie.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import (
    SESSION_KEY, BACKEND_SESSION_KEY, HASH_SESSION_KEY,
    get_user_model
)
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore

def create_session_cookie(username, password):

    # First, create a new test user
    user = get_user_model()
    user.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)

    # Then create the authenticated session using the new user credentials
    session = SessionStore()
    session[SESSION_KEY] = user.pk
    session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[0]
    session[HASH_SESSION_KEY] = user.get_session_auth_hash()
    session.save()

    # Finally, create the cookie dictionary
    cookie = {
        'name': settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
        'value': session.session_key,
        'secure': False,
        'path': '/',
    }
    return cookie
```

Now, inside your Selenium tests:

```
#selenium_tests.py

# assuming self.webdriver is the selenium.webdriver obj.
from create_session_cookie import create_session_cookie

session_cookie = create_session_cookie(
    username='test@email.com', password='top_secret'
)

# visit some url in your domain to setup Selenium.
# (404 pages load the quickest)
self.driver.get('your-url' + '/404-non-existent/')

# add the newly created session cookie to selenium webdriver.
self.driver.add_cookie(session_cookie)

# refresh to exchange cookies with the server.
self.driver.refresh()

# This time user should present as logged in.
self.driver.get('your-url')
```

Comment: I tried this and apparently the cookie domain didn't match.

Comment: The error I get (Django 1.10 Python 3.5) is: `Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Cookies are disabled inside 'data:' URLs.`

Comment: This worked for me... I added 'create_session_cookie(self)' method to a base selenium class and used it across tests... If anyone is confused on how to this comment here I would add a complete example.

Comment: How would I modify this code if I want the session cookie of an existing user? @F.ENoelNfebe & tilacog

Comment: @n00b do you know the name of the cookie? or how to get it? It's easy to pick up cookies if you know the name.

Comment: I think there is some confusion in the code and the middle bit should be:
`user_model = get_user_model()`   and then 
`user = user_model.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)`

Comment: @F.ENoelNfebe Can you please share full example? It doesn't work on my end.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library available on GitHub for this purpose: [django-selenium-login](https://github.com/feffe/django-selenium-login)