# How to login user during Given step using django-behave

Tags: python, django, python-behave

I'm using django-behave to run behavioural tests in a Django project. In my feature file I have this given step in several scenarios:

```
 Given I am logged in
```

What I've been doing so far is use Selenium to go through the login process manually. But that takes a long time and it's not what I'm testing at this point. Plus the [behave documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/gherkin.html?highlight=client#when) says:

> Requests/Twill/Selenium interaction etc should mostly go into When steps

So how should I log in a user during this Given step? Is there a way to use django.test.Client.login()? Can I just put a session into a fixture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, using [this answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497239/4884772), I've gone for this:

```python
@given('I am logged in')
def impl(context):
    client = context.test.client
    client.login(email='test@email.com', password='password')

    cookie = client.cookies['sessionid']

    # Selenium will set cookie domain based on current page domain.
    context.browser.get(context.get_url('/404-loads-fastest/'))
    context.browser.add_cookie({
        'name': 'sessionid',
        'value': cookie.value,
        'secure': False,
        'path': '/',
    })
```

But it still seems kind of indirect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the original author of django-behave. I've opened a ticket to improve the documentation on how to login.

https://github.com/django-behave/django-behave/issues/65

I've done it different ways depending on the django system under test: on one site, it's using the standard Django login, on another, the login is done via an Ajax call, on a 3rd, I'm using a 3rd party system for authentication.

So there is no single way; I write one piece of logic for each system as you have done.

Comment: Rachel, like your other answer today these are not answers. They are "I will look into it"

Comment: Disagree with you Drew: Rachel's named three ways to solve the problem and said the right one depends on the system under test.

Comment: @LikeJasper But the question is "How to log in a user ..." and this attempt to answer merely gives some bullet points. I usually expect a bit more from an answer. As useful as it is - I think it resembles more a comment than an answer. Why not making it a comment then (or extend the answer)?

Comment: Alright, it is an attempt at an answer, or is an answer. So I was wrong.